# How to replace only string from the html content in php

Tags: php, laravel

How to replace only string from the html content in php?

Example : 
Html :

```
<div>
    <a class="active" href="link">My String</a>
</div>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li><i fa fa-list></i>List 1</li>
        <li><i fa fa-list></i>List 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Excepted Result:

```
<div>
    <a class="active" href="link">My Replace String</a>
</div>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li><i fa fa-list></i>List 1</li>
        <li><i fa fa-list></i>Replace List 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Purpose of this is to translate only string and replace it in html content.

Try: I have tried the dom but its not close proper tags

```
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($language_value, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
    /*echo $language_value.'<br>.........';*/
    foreach($xpath->query('//text()') as $text)
    {
        if (trim($text->nodeValue)) {
            $search = $text->nodeValue;
            /*echo $text->nodeValue.'<br>';*/

            $text->nodeValue = $tr->translate($source, $code, $text->nodeValue, $attempts);
            /*$text->nodeValue = str_replace($search,$replace,$text->nodeValue);*/
            /*echo $text->nodeValue.'<br>';*/
        }
    }
    $result = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what your problem is, but the start HTML is a document fragment (it doesn't have a root node).  This may cause the HTML to be changed when creating the final output as `loadHTML()` will try and *correct* it.  If you add a new `<div>` round the content it should be constructed properly.

Comment: There are potentially a few different options for this. Is the string stored in a database of some sort?

Comment: Also, what is `<i fa fa-list>` ? I am assuming it is `<i class='fa fa-list'>`.

Answer (score 0):

First your HTML string must be a **`valid HTML`**

Then you may use  `$node->nodeValue` to set your replacement text

```
//...

$domString = "
<div><a class='active' href='link'>My String</a></div> 
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><i class='fa fa-list'></i>List 1 </li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-list'></i>List 2 </li>
  </ul>
</div>";
$dom = new \DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($domString, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xPath = new \DOMXPath($dom);


foreach($xPath->query("//a") as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = "My replacement string";
}

foreach($xPath->query("//li") as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = "My replacement list";
}

$result = $dom->saveHTML();
//...
```

Check demo Repl [here](https://repl.it/@FMOUSSI/replace-only-string-from-the-html-content-in-php)

Comment: $node->nodeValue overwrites the existing content with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

I wouldn't recommend it as it would suppress the errors that libxml throws. You would really want to check on whether the HTML is well formed or not(or if it's really a HTML text).

For your case, you can use [getElementsByTagName](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to get all the `li` tags. Now, you can loop over all matched `li` elements and edit only the element that appears 2<sup>nd</sup> in your list, since you want to edit only the 2<sup>nd</sup> `li` element.

However, while doing so, you have a child node and a text node(having the text `List 2`). You may want to edit only the text node and leave all other nodes as is.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('
<div><a class="active" href="link">My String</a></div> 
<div>
<ul>
<li><i class="fa fa-list"></i>List 1</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-list"></i>List 2</li>
</ul>
</div>');

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('li') as $index => $node){
    if($index === 1){ // to skip first li tag(since you want the 2nd one)
        foreach($node->childNodes as $child_node){
            if($child_node instanceof DOMText){
                $child_node->nodeValue = 'Replacement List 2';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/plPa6

Important point to note here is that the `DOMDocument` has added the `DOCTYPE`,`html` and `body` tags as well to your HTML as your initial HTML wasn't properly structured hierarchically.

Comment: Yes, it work only fixed html struture. but my html structure are not fixed, it dynamic. Is any solution which use any structure of html